# microsoft.interop.selection text

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in, office-interop

Before asking my question I would like to describe briefly background of my problem: I'm developing ms word COM addin on C# and I need to handle user's text selections. Now I'm able to catch selection event - it's look like

```
Microsoft.Interop.Word._Application app;
app = (Word._Application )Application; // Application object comes on addin's connection
app.Application.WindowSelectionChange+= 
            new Word.ApplicationEvents4_WindowSelectionChangeEventHandler(selChange);

///
void selChange(Word.Selection selection){

   MessageBox.Show(selection.Text); // this is my problem, Text property is not available

}
```

// property Text doesn't exist,but [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.text%28v=office.11%29.aspx) tells that it exists. I suspect, that this property is not available for ms word 2007 - in the documentation only 2003,2010 versions are mentioned. But how I can do something like `selection.getSelectedText()`? I tryed to play with `selection.Rows`, `selection.Rows[0]`,`selection.Words,selection.Words[0]` - no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb179341%28v=office.12%29.aspx), the `Selection.Text` property should be available for Word 2007 as well. I made a small sample implementation of your case to test it, and I cannot make it fail on Word 2010 and 2013 at least:

```
var wordApplication = new Application() { Visible = true };
wordApplication.Documents.Add();
wordApplication.WindowSelectionChange += delegate(Selection mySelection) { Console.WriteLine(mySelection.Text); };
```

So, I suggest you check that you have included the right namespaces and that the `Selection` interface you are using are actually the one from the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` namespace.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. The problem was not in bad namespaces but in my believing to IDE's autosuggestion - when I typed Selection. autocompilt didn't show me Selection.Text variant but it surprisingly compiled without errors) By the way, your approach with delegate and my event handler works fine - I'm not good in c# but I think it identical approaches.